# No se esta ejecutando un método de una clase

Tags: python

no se porque no se ejecuta un método de una clase.

Esta es la clase,

```
from Persona import Persona
class Estudiante (Persona):
    #constructor
    def __init__ (self, nombre, rut, nota1, nota2):
        super().__init__(nombre,rut)
    #Atributos
        self.__nota1= nota1
        self.__nota2= nota2

# Geters
    def get_nota1 (self):
        return self.nota1
    def get_nota2 (self):
        return self.nota2

#Seters
    def set_nota1 (self, nota1):
        self.__nota1 = nota1
    def set_nota2 (self, nota2):
        self.__nota2 = nota2

#Metodos
    def promedio (self):
        return (float(self.__nota1)+float(self.__nota2))/2

    def ingreso (self):
        self.nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")
        super().set_nombre(self.nombre)
        self.rut=input("Ingrese el RUT del estudiante: ")
        super().set_rut(self.rut)
        self.nota1=input("Ingrese la nota 1: ")
        Estudiante.set_nota1(self,self.nota1)
        self.nota2=input("Ingrese nota 2: ")
        Estudiante.set_nota2(self,self.nota2)

from Estudiante import Estudiante
global estudiantes
estudiantes = list()
e=Estudiante

def menu ():
    op = int(0)
    while int(op) != 4:
        print("Menu")
        print("1.- Registrar")
        print("2.- Listar")
        print("3.- Eliminar")
        print("4.- Salir")
        op:int = input("Seleccione la opción")
        if op == int(1):
            e=Estudiante()
            e.ingreso()
            estudiantes.append(e)
        elif op == int(2):
            for e in estudiantes:
                print(e)
```

El método que no se ejecuta es el ingreso, y la verdad no me arroja nada.
No encuentro cual es el error, primero se ejecutaba correctamente, luego de meterlo en el ciclo, no funciono mas, pero necesito aplicar un ciclo, para registrar personas con esos datos en una lista, luego mostrar dicha lista, y poder eliminar o agregar mas. Pero no logro hacer que funcione ni el ingreso jajaja

Comment: Pues no se ejecuta nada por que la variable op es un string y lo comparas con un int, creo que haces mal la conversión, deberías hacer int(op). Y recuerda que el uso de type hint solo es una ayuda al programador para que sepa que la variable es de cierto tipo pero nada impide que sea de cualquier otro tipo

Comment: El hecho de hacer `op:int` **no** convierte lo ingresado en input a entero, eso no es una forma de casting de datos. Lo que deberías hacer es `op:int = int(input("Seleccione la opción"))` O lo que mencioné antes `int(op) == 1`

Comment: @Angel, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y, así, ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es porque probablemente no has comprendido bien algunos de los conceptos de este lenguaje en particular. Sé que puede resultarte aburrido leer un poco y podrías saltar al final de mi respuesta para *ver* la solución, pero te recomiendo que leas y juegues un poco con el código para aprender estos conceptos, pues ese es el objetivo de los ejercicios de introducción a cualquier lenguaje de programación.

## Tipado dinámico

Comenzaré diciendo que no puedes olvidar que python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico. Es decir, yo puedo asignar a una misma variable valores de distinto tipo y el tipo de esta variable va a depender del objeto que tenga asignado, aceptando libremente que este tipo cambie entre una asignación y otra.

Ejecuta este código:

```
x = 1
print(type(x))
x = "1"
print(type(x))
```

Va a producir una salida similar a:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

Esto no varía por el hecho de utilizar *sugerencias de tipos* (*type hints* en inglés). Mira esto:

```
x:int = 1
print(type(x))
x = "1"
print(type(x))
```

Produce la misma salida del anterior y, quizás de manera sorprendente para ti, esto también es válido y produce la misma salida —no me creas, ejecuta tú mismo el código—:

```
x:str = 1
print(type(x))
x = "1"
print(type(x))
```

La primera línea es una clara contradicción (para un humano). Estoy *declarando* que la variable `x` sea del tipo `str` y en el mismo instante le asigno un entero, lo cual no solo es aceptado por el interprete, sino que después de dicha asignación la variable `x` es del tipo `int`.

Lo he expresado de esa manera para que quede claro qué es lo que el interprete de python *hace* al ejecutar dicho código y eso explica el resultado que obtenemos.

El código es más o menos equivalente a:

```
x:str
x = 1
print(type(x))
x = "1"
print(type(x))
```

Digo más o menos equivalente, porque la primera línea, aunque se ejecuta, en realidad no hace nada. Después de ejecutarlo el *nombre* `x` sigue sin estar definido.

## Comparaciones entre int y str

En mi opinión, python debiera emitir un error al momento de intentar comparar la igualdad de un string y una cadena, pero no lo hace.

Este código se ejecuta exitosamente y produce la salida a continuaciön:

```
entero = 1
cadena = "1"
if entero == cadena:
  print("son iguales")
else:
  print("no son iguales")
```

```
no son iguales
```

Mientras que otros operadores de comparación si producen un error, por ejemplo el mayor que, produce la siguiente salida:

```
entero = 7
cadena = "1"

if entero > cadena:
  print("Es mayor")
else:
  print("no es mayor")
```

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Esto ocurre porque, aunque python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, como hemos visto antes, es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado y dos variables de distinto tipo generalmente no pueden compararse, y en el caso del operador de igualdad, no van a ser iguales.

## Conversión de string a entero

Puedes utilizar la función [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para convertir una cadena a tipo entero. (De manera equivalente puedes utilizar la función [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) para convertir de entero a cadena. Ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
entero = 7
cadena = "1"
cadena = int(cadena)
if entero > cadena:
  print("Es mayor")
else:
  print("no es mayor")
```

Que ahora producirá el resultado:

```
Es mayor
```

En el script anterior voy muy despacio, paso a paso, para que quede claro, pero puedes hacer directamente `int("1")`, por ejemplo, para obtener el mismo resultado.

Por otro lado, si llamo a la función `int()` con un parámetro entero, me devuelve el entero mismo, por ejemplo este código produce la salida a continuación:

```
entero = 7
print(type(entero))
entero = int(entero)
print(type(entero))
x = int(7)
print(type(x))
```

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

## input() devuelve un string

Otra cosa que no debes olvidar es que la función [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) **siempre** devuelve un string, independientemente de si el usuario introduce solo números, o números y letras o símbolos.

## La solución a tus problemas:

Después de leer y comprender lo anterior, los errores en tu código debieran saltar a la vista, pero igual te los voy diciendo:

```
op:int = input("Seleccione la opción")
```

O mejor dicho, dime tú, ¿de que tipo será la *variable* `op` después de ejecutar esta línea?

Es cierto, tienes una *sugerencia de tipo* para que sea entero, pero input devuelve un string. Puedes comprobarlo haciendo un `print(type(op))` después de esta asignación.

Ahora, la condición de este if:

```
if op == int(1):
```

Vamos despacio, primero a la derecha del operador de igualdad encontramos

```
int(1)
```

Como vimos antes, int() si recibe un entero, devuelve el entero mismo, por lo que la expresión es exactamente igual a si tuvieramos:

```
if op == 1:
```

Acá, al lado izquierdo del operador de comparación de igualdad, `op` es una cadena, y a la derecha tenemos un entero. Como ya vimos, el operador de comparación de igualdad siempre va a devolver False si comparamos una cadena con un entero. Nunca va a devolver True

En otras palabras, aunque la cadena contenga el valor `"1"`, el resultado de la comparación va a ser false y el código que esté dentro de este if no se va a ejecutar nunca.

En este punto, espero que seas capaz de darte cuenta que tu conclusión original (y el título de esta pregunta) es incorrecta. **No es que el método de la clase no se ejecute**, sino que nunca lo invocas.

Es decir, obviamente es cierto que no se ejecuta, pero no es porque el programa pase por su invocación y de alguna manera esta falle, sino es que la línea de código que lo invoca, no solo no se ejecuta, sino que está en una *ruta muerta*. Es decir, no hay manera de hacer que se ejecute.

Algunas **recomendaciones adicionales**:

Primero es que hagas la conversión a entero directamente a la hora de pedir el dato al usuario, así no tienes que estar haciendo conversiones para comparar, lo que hace el código más propenso a errores, pero también más difícil de leer.

Sería mejor que hagas algo como:

```
numero = int(input("ingrese un número: "))
if numero == 1:
    print("uno")
elif numero == 2:
    print("dos")
else:
    print("no conozco ese número")
```

Si debes hacer un programa *resistente* a los usuarios (también llamado *robusto*), entonces puedes validar la entrada del usuario antes de convertir a número o manejar la excepción que se produzca al convertir (de otra manera el programa terminará con un error).

El concepto de excepciones y su manejo puede ser avanzado a estas alturas, por lo que puedes valerte del método `.isdigit()` de la cadena para asegurarte que el usuario haya introducido un número entero, Tomando el ejemplo anterior, prueba ahora este código y compara la ejecución con el anterior introduciendo "hola" cuando el programa te pida un número.

```
cadena = input("ingrese un número: ")
if cadena.isdigit():
    numero = int(cadena)
    if numero == 1:
        print("uno")
    elif numero == 2:
        print("dos")
    else:
        print("no conozco ese número")
else:
    print("¡no ingresó un número!")
```